# Google App Engine Entity Manager Configuration with Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, dependency-injection, factory-method

I'm trying to write a Spring configuration for some basic Google App Engine services. In particular for the EntityManagerFactory and Entity Manager.

To create an EntityManagerFactory from Java code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = javax.persistence.Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

Which I would translate as:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="javax.persistence.Persistence" 
    factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="transactions-optional"/> 
</bean>
```

And every time I need an EntityManager

```
EntityManager em = emfInstance.get().createEntityManager();
```

But I don't know how to tell to apply the factory method to the previously created factory.

```
<bean id="entityManagerProto" 
    factory-method="createEntityManager" scope="prototype"/>
```

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use existing bean as a factory as follows:

```
<bean id="entityManagerProto"
    factory-bean = "entityManagerFactory"
    factory-method="createEntityManager" scope="prototype"/>
```

Also, I'm not sure whether it would work on GAE, but perhaps it would be better to use [`LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-lemfb) instead, and get `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: Thank you, but for LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean a note says: *Only use this option in simple deployment environments such as stand-alone applications and integration tests.*

Comment: @stivlo: `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` does exactly the same what you do manually. Spring guys mean that in production environment you may want to obtain `EntityManagerFactory` in a more sophisticated way (as provided by `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`), but it certainly won't work on GAE.

Comment: ah, I understand... I will try then.